# Expex interlinear centering includes punctuation

Tags: horizontal-alignment, linguistics, expex

As you can see in the image below, when using `glwordalign=center`, the punctuation in `\gla` counts as part of the word. As a result, `\glb` and `\glc` are centered not just on the word but also on the punctuation. How can I prevent the punctuation from being counted as part of the word so that only the words align but the punctuation is still there in its proper place?
[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}        
\usepackage{expex}    
\lingset{glwordalign=center}

\begin{document}    
\exdisplay
\begingl
  \gla "aaaaa aaaaaaa!" aaaa aaaa aaaa... //      
  \glb bbbbb bbbbbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb //      
  \glc ccccc ccccccc cccc cccc cccc //      
\endgl
\xe    
\end{document}
```

P.S. ignore the wrong starting quotation mark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `\nogloss` macro to mark unglossed elements in the `\gla` line,  plus the `@` to remove the space.  Note that the spaces around the `@` are required.

```
\documentclass{book}        
\usepackage{expex}    
\lingset{glwordalign=center}

\begin{document}    
\exdisplay
\begingl
  \gla \nogloss{``} @ aaaaa aaaaaaa @ \nogloss{!''} aaaa aaaa aaaa @ \nogloss{\ldots} //      
  \glb bbbbb bbbbbbb bbbb bbbb bbbb //      
  \glc ccccc ccccccc cccc cccc cccc //      
\endgl
\xe    
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: That looks nice. Can that be automated for a long document so that I don't have to do it in line?

Comment: @AML Not trivially, if at all. It would involve making the punctuation marks active characters and then mapping them to the `\nogloss` macro.  I would ask a separate question about that.

Comment: Good idea. Question created here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/383756/make-punctuation-active-characters-and-map-them-to-the-nogloss-macro